# How restart nodeJS application with button on javascript from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, forever-monitor

nodeJS file — main.js

Have a website with button which can call function from main.js. I not know how restart nodeJS script correctly. Now I run `process.exit()` in **main.js** and then, with nodemon trying restart application but nodemon tell me “**[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart**”. So how correctly restart application?

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#manual-restarting

Comment: If you're using nodemon, the server will automatically restart after you save a change to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean exit means exit code **0**, which means, "Everything is okay! I intended to exit." Usually, programs that exit normally don't specifically intend to be restarted. nodemon is choosing to consider that the end of the program's operation, which isn't a totally insane thing. However, nodemon being a process manager for daemons, probably ought to just restart it anyway. I would suggest using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) instead, it is what most people use in production and it will correctly restart the process since its whole job is to keep services running.

Aside from all of that, I want to note that allowing a browser to restart your app is probably not a good idea. If you have carefully designed your app to be stateless and handle random shutdowns and it is clustered, etc. then maybe it is fine. But generally I would not recommend it. At the very least, make sure the request is authenticated and authorized.